# is possible to pd.read_sql with intermediate temp table?

Tags: sql-server, pandas

I have some SQL task in python where I may need to create intermediate temp table.

Is it possible to achieve something like below?

```
sql_command = \
    f"""
        select top 100 * into #tmp123 from  mydb;
        select top 2 * from  #tmp123
    """
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + "myservername") 
table_spec_ret_sql = pd.read_sql(sql_command,cnxn)
```

This current implementation gives me an error saying

> 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `SET NOCOUNT ON` to your batch.

```
sql_command = \
        f"""
            set nocount on;
            select top 100 * into #tmp123 from  mydb;
            select top 2 * from  #tmp123
        """
    import pyodbc
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + "myservername") 
    table_spec_ret_sql = pd.read_sql(sql_command,cnxn)
```

The rowcount message from the first statement comes before the resultset, and client driver needs to consume that before the resultset is available.  Some drivers do this automatically, some don't.